# How do I approach logic questions?

Tags: php, logic

I have been given this question for an interview. I am to show my logic working in PHP:

> John, Alex, Jay, Thomson and May live on different floors of an apartment house that contains only five floors. John does not live on the top floor. Alex does not live on the bottom floor. Jay does not live on either the top or the bottom floor. Thomson lives on a higher floor than does Alex. May does not live on a floor adjacent to Jay’s. Jay does not live on a floor adjacent to Alex’s. Where does everyone live?

How am I meant to approach these sorts of questions? If there some sort of book or training I can get?

My initial thought is to just work out where to "begin" as each one of these sorts must have to be done before the other.

Comment: i would not get this job, probably a good thing

Comment: hahaha.. I wish I could up vote that

Comment: Setup variable names for the 5 people, then a system of equations and inequations corresponding to each statement. Layout a table (array) to represent floor/person combinations. Use any equations to rule out certain options, then apply the inequations recursively to the remaining options. It's easy to test the solution, just run it agains all your equations and inequations.

Comment: This problem is small enough that you can just try all the combinations and test which are valid.

Comment: However, until you add some code and a specific question about that code, you are likely to encounter close votes for not being sufficiently specific or relevant to SO.

Comment: @Dagon as written, this is a bad fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. Just loop through all the possible combinations.

```
<?php

for ($alex = 1; $alex <= 5; $alex++) {
    // note that it states alex does not live on the bottom floor,
    // so you could start alex at 2 here, but then you would have
    // to apply logic to the other counts too, and that will start to
    // get complicated.
    for ($john = 1; $john <= 5; $john++) {
        for ($jay = 1; $jay <= 5; $jay++) {
            for ($thomson = 1; $thomson <= 5; $thomson++) {
                for ($may = 1; $may <= 5; $may++) {

                    // John, Alex, Jay, Thomson and May live on different floors of an apartment house that contains only five floors
                    if (count(array_unique(array($alex, $john, $jay, $thomson, $may))) !== 5) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // John does not live on the top floor
                    if ($john == 5) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Alex does not live on the bottom floor
                    if ($alex == 1) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Jay does not live on either the top or the bottom floor
                    if ($jay == 1 || $jay == 5) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Thomson lives on a higher floor than does Alex
                    if ($thomson < $alex) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // May does not live on a floor adjacent to Jay’s
                    if (abs($may - $jay) == 1) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Jay does not live on a floor adjacent to Alex’s
                    if (abs($jay - $alex) == 1) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    echo 'Alex: floor ' . $alex . '<br>';
                    echo 'John: floor ' . $john . '<br>';
                    echo 'Jay: floor ' . $jay . '<br>';
                    echo 'Thomson: floor ' . $thomson . '<br>';
                    echo 'May: floor ' . $may . '<br>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Solution / output:

```
Alex: floor 2
John: floor 3
Jay: floor 4
Thomson: floor 5
May: floor 1
```